# Why would Process Explorer be unable to verify signature of PortableApps.exe?

Tags: process-explorer, digital-signature, portable-apps

i'm running a program called [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/), which includes an executable called `PortableAppsPlatform.exe`.

The Portable Apps executable is digitally signed:

[image]

And the digital certificate is valid and non expired:

[image]

Yet when i use the "Verify Signer" feature of [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), it reports that it cannot verify the signer:

[image]

Why would Process Explorer be unable the verify the signer of a valid digitally signed executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signing certificate might have expired... or perhaps the certificate was self-signed or signed to look like a valid certificate... or even perhaps the certificate was revoked.  There are a long list of reasons a certificate can become invalid.  Not all of which imply that the software is harmful... but at the very least it is questionable.  If you clicked that "View Certificate" button we might be able to get more information as to why it's now considered invalid.

As far as "Process Explorer" goes... it relies on the Operating system to verify certificates.  It does nothing special.

Comment: i forgot the exact reason; but i think one of the things you listed was right.